# Listview Checkbox select

Tags: android, checkbox, onclick, android-listview

I have created a custom listview which has Image + Text + checkbox. How to detect selecting/ unselecting of the check box. I tried onItemClick() but it won't get called. Have I used it in correctly?

```
 class PInfo {
    String appname = "";
    String pname = "";
    Drawable icon;
 }

public class InstalledApps extends Activity{

private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
private ListView listview;
private Activity activity;

List<PInfo> installedApps = new ArrayList<PInfo>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.applist);

    activity = this;
    listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

    for(ApplicationInfo app : packages) {

        PInfo newInfo = new PInfo();

        newInfo.appname = (String) app.loadLabel(pm);
        newInfo.pname = app.packageName;
        //newInfo.icon = app.icon;
        //Drawable dd = activity.getResources().getDrawable(app.icon);
        newInfo.icon = app.loadIcon(getPackageManager());

        if((app.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP) == 1) {        

            installedApps.add(newInfo);
        } else if ((app.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 1) {

            installedApps.add(newInfo);

        } else {

            installedApps.add(newInfo);

        }
    }


    InstalledAppsAdapter iap = new InstalledAppsAdapter(this, installedApps);
    listview.setAdapter(iap);



}



  }

class InstalledAppsAdapter extends BaseAdapter{


private Activity activity;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
List<PInfo> installedApps = new ArrayList<PInfo>();
ListView listview; 

public InstalledAppsAdapter(Activity a, List<PInfo> b) {

    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    installedApps = b;
    activity = a;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    listview = (ListView)activity.findViewById(R.id.listView1);


       //Here is where I have put it currently..

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            PInfo newInfo = (PInfo) listview.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
            System.out.println(newInfo.appname);
        }
    });
}



@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return installedApps.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    View  customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow, arg2,false);

    ImageView iv = (ImageView)customView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    TextView tv= (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    CheckBox cb= (CheckBox)customView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);


    PInfo pinfo = installedApps.get(arg0);

        tv.setText(""+pinfo.appname);
        iv.setImageDrawable(pinfo.icon);



    return customView;


}

}
```

Where should I add this code(if this is the right listner),

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            PInfo newInfo = (PInfo) listview.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
            System.out.println(newInfo.appname);
        }
    });
```

Thanks..

Comment: why you are setting `onClickListener()` on `ListView` rather set it on `checkBox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the code inside `getView`

```
@Override
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub


View  customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow, arg2,false);

ImageView iv = (ImageView)customView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
TextView tv= (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
CheckBox cb= (CheckBox)customView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
{
    if ( isChecked )
    {
        // perform logic
    }

}
});
}


PInfo pinfo = installedApps.get(arg0);

    tv.setText(""+pinfo.appname);
    iv.setImageDrawable(pinfo.icon);



return customView;


}
```

Comment: I want to use the back button press on listview. However I cant define it inside the InstalledAppsAdapter. So I have to define it inside the InstalledApps class. When I press the back button from the listview it gets called but not when in the main view..I want to capture both events on the back press. Any ideas on how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Insted of keeping check box u may use simple_list_item_multiple_choice in choise mode.